# flutter: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_retry, permanent: true

Tags: ios, flutter, speech-to-text, permanent

i am using the speech_to_text package in my app.they work correct on iOS 15 simulator but on iOS 16 and above they give the flutter: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_retry, permanent: true error in console .please suggest me the solution if any one face and solve it before

i don't know because they work fine on iOS 15.. it means there is no issue in code the issue is with platform compatibility .i was search allot but did not find any useful solution